MarketingCloudSDK-iOS repository has been Archived
The repository for the iOS MarketingCloudSDK has been archived:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS
Is there a replacement available?
All the documentation I've found contains links to the archived repository.

Can we get an answer on this? There are enterprises relying on this SDK.
